# how to create a http proxy api gateway from serverless without creating lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, serverless, serverless-plugins

**I have to create http proxy api gateway from serverless code for this flow:** https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-with-microservices-deployed-on-amazon-ecs/

Answer (score -1):

You only need to know how to build an ECS cluster including a Load Balancer, then you can enable HTTP proxy on API Gateway console.

- How to build an ECS cluster?
  a) Create an ECS Cluster
  b) Create a Task Definition and set your image on it
  c) Create a Load Balancer and Target Group
  d) Create an ECS Service and attach Load Balancer and Task Definition

You can follow the official guide here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-ec2.html